# How to execute logic after populate() in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have  a User schema which contains 2 sub-documents - Academics and MaskedFields . Now these 2 sub-documents are schema of their own.

What I want to do is - create a field in the User schema which will contain a list of all keys  in the User schema. The keys can be nested. Now, the logic for finding the keys is working fine. However, I want to embed this logic in one of the pre-hooks (init for now).

What I have right now is -

The actual query for the User schema -

```
User.find({ _id: id }).populate("academics maskedField")
```

The fields - `academics` and `maskedFields` are virtual properties on User schema pointing to Academics and `MaskedFields` schema.

Now, to add the property called `fieldsToBeMasked` that would contain the list of available keys of the above query, I have written the logic in User schema's pre-init hook as follows -

```
userSchema.pre('init', async function (data) {
    fieldsToBeMasked = Formatter.getObjectKeys(data)
    data.fieldsToBeMasked = fieldsToBeMasked

})
```

The method - `getObjectKeys()` will recursively traverse the data JSON and list out all the keys.

Now the issue is, the above hook is fired before the `.populate()` query. As a result, I only get the keys present in the User schema. I am not able to get the `academics` and `maskedFields` schema data. From what I understand, the following is the order of execution -

1. User query - `find()`
2. `pre-init` hook fired
3. List all keys in `User` document only
4. Apply populate() on the User document
5. Get the complete result set - `User` (academics + maskedFields) and `fieldsToBeMasked` ( but `fieldsToBeMasked` now only contains keys of the `User` schema minus the `academics` and `maskedFields` schema )

So, my question is, is there a hook or any other facility through which I can trigger this logic of listing all keys after the `.populate()` method is called ?

**EDIT 1 -**

So, as mentioned the .find() is a common function that is invoked by the respective collections (as this is a faas and I wanted to re-use the same endpoint for all queries)

The main -

```
const collectionList = {
    'User': User,
    'Academics': Academics
}

const populateList = {
    "User": "academics maskedfields",
    "Academics": "user"

}

    const collection = collectionList[req.params.collection];
    const id = req.params.id ? req.params.id : null;
    const populateBy = populateList[req.params.collection]

        try{
                switch (req.method) {
                    case 'GET':
                        resultSet = await collectionGET(collection, populateBy, id)
                        // console.log(resultSet)
                        break;
                    case 'POST':
                        resultSet = await collectionPOST(collection, payload)
                        break;
                    case 'PUT':
                        resultSet = await collectionPUT(collection, id, payload)
                        break;
                    case 'DELETE':
                        resultSet = await collectionDELETE(collection, id)
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Error("Method not allowed")
                }

                res.status(200).send(resultSet)
            } catch (e) {

                res.status(400).send(e.message)
            }
```

As you can see, the `collectionList` contains list of all collections and `populateList` contains list of all virtual fields in each collections.

So for User collection, the .find() method would turn out to be -

```
resultSet = await User.find({ _id: id }).populate( "academics maskedfields")
```

I am not using the callback of `.populate()` method.

Comment: Why not to call this pre-init hook on the result object of populate function ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. How exactly, any idea ?

Comment: Can you give me your entire .populate() function, You could just take the result of the function with in a callback and can operate on it !!

Comment: Well so I am not using the callback of the .populate() function due to reasons not related to the problem at hand ( This is a FaaS code that is used commonly for all the collections available ). However, I have attached the the code above.

Comment: @srinivasy So just to clarify, I can pass the results of the .populate() method to the pre-init function but I was wondering if the same can be achieved by using a hook with populate() method.

Comment: ok,sorry that I'm not aware of any, I was mentioning the same, looking into mongoose docs if I find any will post it here !!

Comment: May seem obvious but why don't you use the `post` hook/middleware? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post

Comment: @Intellidroid Tried post-init hook but modifying any value in this method doesn't reflect in the final result set

Comment: But you can do a `post` `find`?